# Unnamed arrays in structs in Go

Tags: syntax, go

So I can have

```
struct {
    int
    x []int
}
```

However,

```
struct {
    int
    []int
}
```

will result in a `syntax error: unexpected [, expecting }`. Is there a way of having unnamed arrays in structs in Go? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the type of an anonymous field must be a type name or a pointer to a type name. You could declare a new type name that is the same as an array type, and then it would work, but it wouldn't be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

Read [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html). In particular, the section on [Struct types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Struct_types). The Go term to describe what you are looking for is an anonymous field.

> Such a[n] [anonymous] field type must
>   be specified as a type name T or as a
>   pointer to a type name *T, and T
>   itself may not be a pointer type.

`int` is a [type name](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#TypeName). `[]int` is neither a type name nor a pointer to a type name.